# Form input events for Macbook touch bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, macbookpro-touch-bar

Are there *any* events that trigger on `form` elements when a user enters input via the MacBook Touch Bar?

Here is a [trivial example](https://jsfiddle.net/wsoafk2d/1/):

```
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>

(function($) {
  $('#textarea')
    .on('keyup', function() {
      console.log('keyup');
    })
    .on('keydown', function() {
      console.log('keydown');
    })
    .on('keypress', function() {
      console.log('keypress')
    });
})(jQuery);
```

On Safari, when I "type" using the Touch Bar (e.g. tapping on emojis or autosuggested text), I don't see *any* events in the web inspector console. However, the regular keyboard will fire the `keydown`, `keypress`, and `keyup` events as expected.

Comment: Have you tried the `'input'` event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like the touch bar triggers key events.

An alternative would be to listen to the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input).

As stated by the relevant [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input), the event is fired whenever the value is changed, which means that it will work when the touch bar changes the `input`/`textarea` value.

> The DOM input event is fired synchronously when the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element is changed.

Usage:

```
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('input', function (event) {
    // ...
});
```

or...

```
$('textarea').on('input', function (event) {
  // ...
});
```